# CMake - iOS Compile options lost when building from cmd line

Tags: c++, ios, cmake

I am new to CMake, and i am trying to cross-build a C executable for ALL iOS platforms.
So, i wrote a CMakeLists.txt as the following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.2)

project(myProject C)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS YES)

set(MY_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_source_file.c)

set(MY_INCLUDES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_library(myTarget STATIC ${MY_SOURCES})

target_include_directories(myTarget PRIVATE ${MY_INCLUDES})

target_compile_options(myTarget PUBLIC -Werror -Wall)
```

Then I launch CMake Configuration phase, creating a build folder outside of source tree, and from then executing the command

```
cmake -G Xcode  -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS -S my_source_dir_path -B .
```

Everything seems fine, an Xcode project file is created within the Build tree. If I open it with XCode and build from this IDE, the "-Werror" and "-Wall" flags are actually used for compilation.
On the contrary, if I type

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

from the same Build tree directory, from the output appearing on the console i see that the flags used for completely different from the one set in CMake file and produced XCode project file. Here's an extract of the Compiler output for a given translation unit

```
    ...
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -target arm64-apple-ios13.1 -fmessage-length=171 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O3 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-missing-braces 
    -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion 
-Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof
    ...
```

It seems therefore that my Target Compile options are being overwritten...
Any idea on what is happening?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `myTarget` ?

Comment: Sorry, myTarget is the name of my Target, i was wrong in other statements leaving the original name

Comment: Well actually I don't see the problem here. The XCode output sample doesn't mention the file `my_source_file.c` at all, so I see no reason to assume it is wrong. There is no output of libraries that are linked to `myTarget` either.

Comment: The Xcode output is just an extract..and the names are invented..the purpose of the extract was to show that compilation flags are actually different from the ones contained in CMakeLists.txt file